Difficult Integral to solve.
Is there a way to simply this and solve it?  It's supposed to be
$\pi$.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac1{1 + (x + \tan(x))^2} dx
$$
Thanks.


"Difficult integral to evaluate."  Equations are solved; expressions are evaluated.

I think the trick to this one is Glasser.

Late on the gun again for a duplicate... No blame on you, Steve237, it was posted a while back. See this question here for a few different approaches to this integral. In the future, Approach0 is an excellent tool to use to check if your question has been asked before.

Eric, very useful comment, Thanks!    Glasser, Teadawg1337, great links, sorry I did not see this was already solved, Thanks....
